# List not being displayed in DropDown Menu at View

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am just learning MVC. Here's What I have tried so far:

```
public class StoreXml
{
    public string StoreCode { get; set; } 


    public static IQueryable<StoreXml> GetStores()
    {
        return new List<StoreXml>
        {
            new StoreXml { StoreCode = "0991"},
            new StoreXml { StoreCode = "0015"},
            new StoreXml { StoreCode = "0018"}
        }.AsQueryable();
    }
```

In Controller:

```
public SelectList GetStoreSelectList()
    {   
        var Store = StoreXml.GetStores();
        return new SelectList(Store.ToArray(),"StoreCode");
    }

    public ActionResult IndexDDL()
    {
        ViewBag.Store = GetStoreSelectList();
        return View();
    }
```

In View:

```
@Html.DropDownList("store", ViewBag.Stores as SelectList, "Select a Store")
```

What am I doing wrong here? Dropdown shows Cie_Mvc.Models.StoreXml only but no values. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You're storing it in `ViewBag.Store` and calling it in the `View`, `ViewBag.Stores`

```
public ActionResult IndexDDL()
{
     ViewBag.Stores = GetStoreSelectList();
     return View();
}

@Html.DropDownList("store", ViewBag.Stores as SelectList, "Select a Store")
```

As a side note, this is the issue with using a `dynamic` `object`. I would suggest putting the property in a `ViewModel`, so you get intellisense.

Comment: Thanks Gabe, I used ViewBag.Stores in both the cases. And still the same.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it differently.  I would separate my class from my list of the classes like:

```
public class StoreXml
{
     public string StoreCode { get; set; }
}
```

Then I would use something like a repository to get some data, even if it is hard coded, or you can just populate a list from your controller.  Always use a view model to represent your data on the view:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
     public string StoreXmlCode { get; set; }

     public IEnumerable<StoreXml> Stores { get; set; }
}
```

And then your controller can look something like this:

```
public class MyController
{
     public ActionResult MyActionMethod()
     {
          MyViewModel viewModel = new MyViewModel();

          viewModel.Stores = GetStores();

          return View(viewModel);
     }

     private List<StoreXml> GetStores()
     {
          List<StoreXml> stores = new List<StoreXml>();

          stores.Add(new StoreXml { StoreCode = "0991"});
          stores.Add(new StoreXml { StoreCode = "0015"});
          stores.Add(new StoreXml { StoreCode = "0018"});

          return stores;
     }
}
```

And then your view could look something like this:

```
@model MyProject.ViewModels.Stores.MyViewModel

@Html.DropDownListFor(
     x => x.StoreXmlCode,
     new SelectList(Model.Stores, "StoreCode", "StoreCode", Model.StoreXmlCode),
     "-- Select --"
)
```

I hope this can lead you in the right direction :)